# If statement css change .. fire only once

Tags: jquery, triggers

```
if( $('.element[value!=""]').length === 1 ) {
    $(".element").css({"width":"50px"});
}
```

I'd like this to fire once, independent of the initial click trigger. Currently each time the if statement is called, the css change gets fired.

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: can u provide a fiddle?

Comment: Why does it matter to you if the same CSS value gets set over and over? Please clarify.

Comment: is this valid: `value!=""` ?

Comment: This was a simplified problem. I agree that it wouldn't matter if the css got fired repeatedly, but the other 10 things happening would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fired = false;

if( ($('.element[value!=""]').length === 1) && !fired) {
    $(".element").css({"width":"50px"});
    fired = true;
}
```

That or remove the click handler from whatever element is triggering this. It fires once, removes the click handler, and can't fire anymore.

Comment: Love this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions, but without seeing the context of your conditional it is impossible for me to suggest what might be best. That being said, from what you've posted here I would implement a simple variable to hold the trigger state and then a condition to the if statement as such:

```
var foo = false; //foo is more terse ;-)
if( $('.element[value!=""]').length === 1 && !foo) {
  $(".element").css({"width":"50px"});
  foo = true;
}
```

Comment: its exactly the same, marc just chose a different variable name and happened to submit his answer while i was typing mine. good luck!